# Unable to get Etag for larger online txt file uploaded to dropbox

Tags: java, android, http-headers, dropbox-api, last-modified

I need to get the etag value of a txt file from its URL, the txt file is uploaded on dropbox.

The etag is a part of the http header of the txt url.

If the file is really small, say 5-10 characters, the code shows the etag value np.

But if the file is 4000 characters or more it returns a null for the etag value. Help needed here, I do not know why this happens.

Here's my code.

```
public void getDatabaseEtag(){
        try {


            URL url = new URL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/<EDITED>.txt");
            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(false);
            con.setReadTimeout(20000);
            con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");

            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0");
            ((HttpURLConnection) con).setRequestMethod("HEAD");


            Map<String, List<String>> map = con.getHeaderFields();

            System.out.println("Printing Response Header...\n");

            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() 
                        + " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
            }

            System.out.println("\nGet Response Header By Key ...\n");
            String etag = con.getHeaderField("ETag");

            if (etag == null) {
                System.out.println("Key 'ETag' is not found! in GetDatabaseEtag()");
            } else {
                //to string in internal storage etag
                stringToTxt(etag,"data_etag.txt");
                System.out.println("ETag - " + etag);
            }

            System.out.println("\n Done");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have to stop posting the same question over and over. Look up the Dropbox API and figure out when the ETag header is sent. You can't force a server to do anything.

Comment: @sotirios- It's not the same question, this is a different issue. If you can't help me atleast try to post something useful please. As you pointed out in the last question, I was 'escaping the point of my question' and hence had to post a new one. The website gives me a maximum of 6 so I'm very well within the rules to do so. Thanks. Edit: I've worked with the dropbox api and it does not suit my purposes.

Comment: FYI, we're taking a look at this on the Dropbox side and will respond to your support ticket. I don't think there's much to do here on Stack Overflow; this looks like a Dropbox issue. (As I said on another question, the availability of ETags aren't documented, so there's no guarantee that this will work in general, but it seems odd that they work only on small files.)

Comment: @smarx- nice to know you work for dropbox (?). I did generate a support ticket. Thanks for the info.